# set a property when entity is loaded from DB

Tags: symfony, properties, doctrine-orm

I have an entity called InvoiceItemMarchandise, with a property "quantity" and a property "previousQuantity" :

```
class InvoiceItemMarchandise extends InvoiceItem
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="integer", nullable=true)
     * @Type("integer")
     */
    protected $quantity;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $previousQuantity;
}
```

$quantity is managed by ORM and stored into DB. When my entity is loaded from DB, I would like to push $quantity value into $previousQuantity, because I will need this value later, when dealing with stock. But i dont want it to be saved in database. I tried to do this in __construct, but I think __construct is only called when I create a new object, not when it is loaded from DB.

How can I do this ?

Comment: A postLoad listener: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#postload and http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Comment: However it might be easier to just tweak your setQuantity and getPreviousQuantity methods.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I'm trying to think if there are ramifications for this beyond the intended scope, so when taking on this solution please understand that I'm undecided on whether or not this a good architectural decision.

But, it could be just as simple as

```
public function setQuantity($quantity)
{
  $this->previousQuantity = $this->quantity;
  $this->quantity = $quantity
}
```

When Entity classes are loaded from the DB, they are hydrated with the property setters, so this *should* work. You may want to ad a special case for when `InvoiceItemMarchandise::$previousQuantity` is null.

Comment: actually I used the postLoad listener as advised in a comment above, as I already had some other events running on this entity. And i need this previousQuantity to stay the same during the whole script. Didn't want it to change when I update the quantity.